# Simple problem with a bar graph

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to do a simple bar chart, but I can't get rid of additional elements in the x axis legend.
The graph function adds a "2001" and "2022" at both extremes of the x axis legend.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.15}
```

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar, 
        %enlargelimits=0.15,
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=Number of publications,
        % remove comma in xticklabels
        xticklabel style={rotate=270, /pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}},
        % one tick every year
        xtick distance=1
        ]
        \addplot table {
            Date GDP 
            2002    1
            2003    0
            2004    0
            2005    0
            2006    1
            2007    0
            2008    0
            2009    1
            2010    2
            2011    3
            2012    3
            2013    2
            2014    4
            2015    2
            2016    3
            2017    3
            2018    3
            2019    2
            2020    7
            2021    8
        };
        % if you have the file, you can do
        % \addplot table {datafile.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!. Just add `xtick={2002,...,2021},` to the axis options.

Comment: Would be nice to include a screenshot next time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the hint that was already given, see `%<<==`, and place the `xtick-option` somewhere in the `axis-definition`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,openany]{book}% whatever your class may be
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=14cm,compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar, 
        %enlargelimits=0.15,
        xlabel=Year,
        ylabel=Number of publications,
        % remove comma in xticklabels
        xticklabel style={rotate=270, /pgf/number format/set thousands separator={}},
        xtick={2002,...,2021},% <<==
        % one tick every year
        xtick distance=1
        ]
        \addplot table {
            Date GDP 
            2002    1
            2003    0
            2004    0
            2005    0
            2006    1
            2007    0
            2008    0
            2009    1
            2010    2
            2011    3
            2012    3
            2013    2
            2014    4
            2015    2
            2016    3
            2017    3
            2018    3
            2019    2
            2020    7
            2021    8
        };
        % if you have the file, you can do
        % \addplot table {datafile.csv};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Result]